# ruby: symlink doesnt exist yet trying the command says it does?

Tags: bash, centos6, ruby, symlink

I've borked something up somehow.  On one of my servers, if I type `ruby`, I get the error `bash: /opt/rh/rh-ruby23/root/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory`

`which ruby` gives:

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

`which -a ruby` gives:

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

I had installed a version of ruby at `/opt/rh/rh-ruby23` via `yum install rh-ruby23` but I then removed with `yum remove rh-ruby-23`

I'm at a loss as to what's still pointing at `/opt/rh/rh-ruby23/root/usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: are either of those you found symlinks? `readlink -f /usr/local/bin/ruby`

Comment: `/usr/bin/ruby` is a symlink to `/usr/local/bin/ruby`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think I had `su -` to root twice...after `exit`ing I saw that I was still logged in as root.  Tried `ruby` again, it worked as expected and was pointing to the correct version.

I'm not sure why, but that must have been the cause?